# Difference between tag search and keyword search results format

Tags: support, bug, search, tag-search

When performing a [tag] search, the results show users' gravatar, badge count & rep, while a keyword search only shows username and a timestamp. Why is the format of results different?

Comment: The first gives you a question list page (with `/questions/tagged/`), the second a search result page (with `/search?q=`). But I suspect the question is a bit deeper than that?

Comment: I'm just typing things into a search bar.  Regardless of how that's queried on the back end, I would normally expect result sets to be presented in the same format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stack Exchange search engine is smart/perky enough to convert a *search* for a single tag to a *redirect* to the tag's page. At that moment, you're *not* in the search results anymore; you're in a part of the site which falls under the umbrella of [question lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/). Those pages have additional benefits over the search results page:

- [live refresh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-refresh)
- more options for sorting and filtering

These options are most useful when you're searching for questions you can answer, rather than when you're looking for a specific question or answer, but in those cases you are likely to use keywords as well and you are not redirected.

I guess that additional functionality was the reason for this redirect, but I couldn't find a Meta post introducing this feature, let alone the official reasoning behind this design choice. The search results page has to support both questions and answers, so that's why it has a different layout, and the other layout already existed.

If you do want the layout of the search page, because [in the near future the question list might look different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/295232)<sup>*</sup>, simply [append `is:q` to your query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%5bsupport%5d%20is%3aq):

[image]

<sup>*: I realize the search page may get a redesign in the future as well. Time will tell what happens ...</sup>

Comment: Thanks.  But what about [searches for multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+javascript)? Those show a list of search results but aren't the "tag's page" but just a list of questions filtered by the tag criteria.  It seems the layout changes when anything else gets added.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand what the purpose of creating two different layouts for a list of search results is.  Your answer illustrates some differences and when they occur - but sheds not much light on *why* this design choice was made.

Comment: I couldn't find an authoritative post about this design choice, but I've expanded my answer a bit with possible reasoning.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to expand on your answer. Even if not 100% certain, your reasoning is sound.